# Updates to the site

Tags: discussion, design

My name is Stéphane and I'm a designer at Stack Exchange, you may have noticed some updates to the design lately.

The updates are part of a SE network-wide update which allows us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on high definition displays
- Fix old layout bugs
- to fix any layout bugs more easily (and faster)
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

If you see any bugs please let us know.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this update, I really like the new design.

Comment: Ugh! That's horrible. :( I don't like change!

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's probably just a matter of getting used :).

Comment: @Surb: Yes, probably. Still pretty horrible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila :), for me it's principally the orange which is weird, but the rest is definitely "sharper" as already said by Stéphane.

Comment: Should this be featured?

Comment: @Surb: Sharper or not, I think it's high time I disallow site-chosen fonts, this change is just awful. Which is a shame, since I'm usually a fan of good typography. But since I spend much of my time online on this very site, I figured it worth the shot.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I completely agree. This change is **horrible**. Also, the blue bounty indicators are really annoying me.

Comment: @Woodface this would be great :).

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do not worry, I will provide you with more cheese that you can place at your sole discretion, which shall never be moved by anyone other than you :P (Please give it a bit of time, and then come back with any specific things that still really stick out at you). I know you don't like change, but please allow a bit of time to acclimate, and let us know what still bothers you.

Comment: ***General note to all*** Feedback is good, we love it, we _need_ it, but we need it in the form of answers that illustrate _one_ particular thing at a time that you find suboptimal with a _constructive_ note as to why :) We understand 'horrible',  but that's kind of broad and difficult to process. Thanks for bearing with us :)

Comment: @Tim: For starters that this is something which just appears. Some warning would have been nice to have. E.g. in the form of a meta announcement that there will be an upcoming change in a day or two. I came to meta to report a bug in the CSS and found an announcement that a change had been made. Maybe I would have felt less visually offended if I'd know it's coming.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair and valid point, duly noted and taken.

Comment: (-1) The choice of new font face is horrible. it is much thinner than before. Instead of much sharper image as what one naively think, it make it one much harder to read (especially for those with poor eyesight).

Comment: @Tim: In the meantime, feel free to contact me for a shipping address. I expect Halloumi, Labneh, Emek and Parmesan cheeses.  :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila +1 for "visually offended" xD

Comment: @achillehui, could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: would it be possible to change the icons in the list of questions and answers? they are very wide and dont seem very nice.

Comment: Wow - I'm amazed at all the detailed and specific criticisms. Thank you for your work on the site. What I really think these criticisms indicate is that people have come to really like the iconic feel of the site, which is entirely due to you (and the others involved in the design process). Thank you!

Comment: I have to say, I dislike the changes in general.  The text is smaller and lighter and this makes reading the site a lot more straining to my eyes.  It also just seems a lot less aesthetically pleasing to me.  Then again, I always dislike change.

Comment: Yes, warning would be great. Better yet, running a vote for the majority of the changes, such as making the *entire* site painfully soft.

Comment: Can we have all of the soft gray changed to black and perhaps the font slightly thicker(and darker if possible, it may be the thickness), since the text hurts my eyes now, and unless I suddenly need glasses, this seems to be due to the update.

Comment: In actuality, I find users appreciate gradual change far more than a bulk change. Also the ability to veto each of these singular changes would be great.

Comment: The new design is awesome, much easier on the eyes, great job. Some people will complain about anything.

Comment: @Committing You can have the ability to veto every change... on your own site.

Comment: @Incurrence actually since my eyes are awful and the screen is tiny everything is blown up to 175%.

Comment: @Incurrence the zoom is a feature in Chrome, it says how much it's zoomed in. Pages default to 175% for me.

Comment: useless and much less aesthetic.....-1 for this initiative

Comment: @Asaf Probably this update is rough because it is being rushed in order to meet the April 21 deadline when Google rolls out a new page-ranking algorithm whose score will now include mobile friendliness, see the [announcement here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/02/finding-more-mobile-friendly-search.html) and google "mobilegeddon".

Comment: @Bill: Hmm, interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @Asaf So we should probably be more patient if we wish SE to preserve the stellar  google page ranks of our posts, e.g. [this joke about AC/BT](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6489/242) currently ranks as the third entry on googling "axiom of choice".  Ouch...

Comment: @Bill: Not for me. But it is a well-known fact that Google personalizes and tempers with results. I get this ranked fifth, after Wikipedia, Eric Schechter's homepage, Wolfram MathWorld, and SEP. Then there's that joke, and the question about AC and AD (which I have answered nearly four years ago). But to your actual point, I'm sure that SE is not trying to sabotage their popularity with this, and I have no doubt the goal is to improve as well to maintain high PageRank scores. I still felt like that change was quite horrible, and was sprung on us like a Jack-in-the-box.

Comment: @Asaf A typo, it's actually fourth for me, before SEP. I agree that it would have been nice to have some advance notice. I can no longer easily discern visited link contrast in some places on main. Do you see the same problem, e.g. in the 10K tools, after you visit a link.

Comment: @Bill: You're asking me? The one who until yesterday, for three years, thought that some green plastic card is yellow, and only found that out by accident? The new color scheme for links is too much orange on meta; and too much... teal(?) on main. I'm glad that finally other people know how it's like to not be sure which text is the actual link, and which text is not. Welcome to my world. (By the way, this was pointed out in one of the many answers below, I think.)

Comment: Why hasn't this update affected MathOverflow? Is it because it is "strictly not affiliated with SE" (in my naive understanding)?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar The conversion of each site to the new platform is a separate task. SE designers go through the designs one by one. For example, today, [android.se] and [graphicdesign.se] got updated. (Check out the voting animations on Android!) I suppose MO's turn will come sooner or later.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar We will do MathOverflow, it's on the list :). But keep in mind that we have to convert all of our sites so it takes time, but I can tell you that we do everything we can to finish this work as soon as possible.

Comment: @pizza and Stéphane: Great! I really loved this new transition and I'd love it if this change would happen to MathOverflow as well! (Though, of course, this is only my opinion.)

Comment: @Tim, Stéphane: Are you planning to address all the issues here at some point, or just those that you're going to fix, in hope that we'll get used to the others before long?

Comment: @StéphaneMartin Is anything going to be done about the [rendering inconsistency](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20096/242) between the preview and answer? This is really annoying and probably an easy fix (just as it was the [last time)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1006/242)

Comment: @StéphaneMartin What about the highly voted, unresolved answers that remain? (Notably the non-monospace comment writing font.)

Comment: @StéphaneMartin: Hi Stéphane. Can you look into the issue that I’ve raised [in this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20496/typesetting-issues-the-map-from-preview-to-published-post-is-not-isometric)? Thanks.

Comment: Are you guys still considering to fix the things mentioned here?

Comment: Yes we're still working on it @AsafKaragila

Comment: @Stéphane: Thanks for letting me know! I hope you noticed that I edited one of the issues (with the benefit of how to correct it in one of two ways).

Comment: @Stéphane I think you should do some substantial work listening and reacting to end users before you start rolling this out to any more sites. I'm not aware of any issue it fixes and I can see many it creates.  This is a missed opportunity to bring the interface up to today's standards.  Get yourself a login to Microsoft ToDo for what people expect these days, or even WhatsApp or Evernote. There's no reason why the desktop experience should be worse than the mobile one.

Comment: @Robert I think you're in the wrong thread. This one is about changes to the site made three years ago.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I blame the new interface

Answer (score 39):

I am a bit inconvenienced by the use of very light grey hues. This only affects a small number posts, so not a pressing concern. Just this morning I was typing a comment to a new user, whose (totally misplaced) post was getting the usual amount of negative attention. It had reached a score of -3, and was faded out accordingly. Except that I still had to see what I was typing.

[image]

I'm in my early 50s, and I could still manage. Barely. But in less favorable lighting it might have been impossible. We have some active users in their seventies. At least one of them has confided that they occasionally have problems here due to impaired vision. Granted, such users rarely need to squint at posts at -3 or below, but anyway.

I realize that changing this one shade will cause an avalanche of other changes in the color scheme (for it to be consistent).

Just a reminder that visually pleasing to the average eye may be near illegible to a weaker one.

Other moderators (judging from the exchange in our chat room) also seem to think that the use of the greyscale spectrum went a bit too far towards the light end.

If this can be fixed by adjusting the settings of my laptop or my browser (FF v36) please tell me :-)

Comment: And we should again bring to attention the crowd of color blinded users which may have some issues with particularly similar shades, especially in a low-contrast environment.

Answer (score 37):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for your feedback, I updated the color to #333 (as it was before). It will be live after our next production build.

---

The voting arrows/text seem faded, as if they are disabled.

Comment: That was actually my *first* observation before coming to meta to figure out what the hell went wrong.

Comment: @crash I second that. Improvement suggestion: Make a hover background to emphasize the arrow actually functions. Since the active version is red and the neutral is gray, maybe a dark blue bg on hover will help recognition.

Comment: @AlexR Or it could just go back to the way it was... :)

Comment: @crash Or that. Although I fear a new design pledges for new colors. The old ones have much more saturation.

Comment: @AlexR I'll stop clogging things up with comments now, but I'm so disappointed with just the sheer volume of all the changes brought with no warning (I see Asaf addressed this already). Everything seemed to function fine and everyone was happy for the most part. Given the traffic this question has generated in just a few hours, there seem to be more negative things wrought upon us than good (there certainly are some good changes, but I think the negative far outweigh the good so far). It's unfortunate.

Comment: @crash +1 for the lack of announcement. I guess we'll accustom to the changes and some stuff is actually good, but the thread asks for issues, not for positive feedback ^^ I take the upvotes as some sort of approval of the new design. An example of what I like is the added padding around the comment text field and that it is larger now (fits 4 lines without scrolling).

Comment: The color of the arrows [has hardly changed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20079/).

Comment: I don't understand this change. New users often miss the arrows and need to be guided to "press the button to accept/vote"; if anything they should be made *more* obvious. It is true that the arrows themselves have not changed color, but the text was a very prominent bold black and is now lighter and thinner, making some people mistake it for being disabled. I strongly recommend beefing up the text again.

Comment: Where do you click to log in. There used to be a "login" in the header.

Comment: @Andrew: Login still seems to be there in the header(tried in an incognito window). If you are already logged in, there is a chat bubble type icon at the top right for me which I can use to logout etc.

Answer (score 28):

<s>[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for your feedback, I set the font family to the default font we are using on the site (Helvetica Neue/Helvetica/Arial/sans-serif) instead of the serif font.</s>

---

Could the typeface in the textbox for entering comments please go back to monospaced? The proportional typeface is not good for editing markdown or (especially) MathJax source.

> [image: screenshot]

**Edit:** The typeface has now changed to sans-serif but it still fails to be monospaced:

> [image: new screenshot]

*"The default font we are using on the site (Helvetica Neue/Helvetica/Arial/sans-serif)"* specifically won't do here -- it should be "mono", possibly as a fallback after something like Lucida Console or Consolas.

Comment: @Stéphane: No, this doesn't seem to be fixed to me. See screenshot. The _question/answer_ edit boxes have monospaced font, but the comment box still doesn't.

Comment: Patience... the new build hasn't rolled out yet.

Comment: "The default font we are using on the site (Helvetica Neue/Helvetica/Arial/sans-serif)" specifically won't do here -- it should be "mono", possibly as a fallback after something like Lucida Console or Consolas.

Comment: This might be one of the few times when you can slam your fist on the desk and say out loud " I want to have mono! " and I hope you haven't missed this chance. :-)

Comment: It seems better now.

Comment: @Asaf: No it doesn't. The typeface is now sans-serif, but it is still not monospaced for me. See new screenshot.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right. Although our sans serif fonts are different, it's clear to me that it's not monospaced.

Comment: It seems the comments are now *displayed* in sans-serif, too. I am not very fond of this mix of fonts, and it would be really strange if this persisted when changed to monospaced. This is not the intent of this proposal, is it?

Comment: @quid: No, the intention is to get the _edit box_ back to monospaced (and presumably the comments, once posted, back to the usual serif typeface).

Answer (score 28):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) I increased the font size from 10px to 12px. It will be live after our next production build.

---

The numbers in some places are unreasonably small, which might be a problem for people like me who have limited vision. Examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also,  little-grey-text-on-white-background doesn't help in the visibility department

Answer (score 27):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for your feedback, it's now fixed and  will be live after our next production build.

---

The comment author and timestamp are now in the same color. Having the timestamp a less intrusive fade gray makes the username more readable (especially with the "just now" text, it disturbs me):

[image] $\ $ as it is now
[image] more like it used to be

Comment: Yes, this is weird and something I haven't seen on any other SE site. My name isn't "[Woodface just now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HRTVs.png)"...

Comment: @Woodface  This is your fault. It is clearly a tribute to your name changes.

Comment: @quidjustnow Possibly...

Comment: @Woodface8hoursago: did you change your name again? :-P

Answer (score 25):

Yet another misalignment:
[image]

The culprit is the `margin-top: -1px` of the `.delete-tag`. A `margin-top: 3px` produces a proper alignment:

[image]

Answer (score 24):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for your feedback, it's now fixed and  will be live after our next production build.

---

Would be cool to have the numbers aligned with the text.

[image]

Properly aligned the list would look like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

Comment: This is due to excess padding of the class `answer-votes`. Judging from the name, it might be used elsewhere as well. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/daOqM.png) for a screenshot with disabled padding. A value of `padding: 0 4px 8px` will keep the old spacing but move the numbers up.

Comment: @AlexR ok... Honestly I don't know what is a "padding".  In the screenshot you linked alignment is *much* better but still not perfect :).

Comment: You can look up any CSS reference on padding if you want to know. Else, the linked screenshot (incorporate it in your post if you want) is styled such that the numbers have _exaclty_ the same baseline as the tags. The rest is due to the font used for the numbers.

Comment: @AlexR ok.. I think I get it (approximately :). "incorporate it in your post if you want" well I propose you that either *you* incorporate it by editing this answer or to make a new answer with the same point and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Done that. I wouldn't edit it in without your consent ;)

Comment: @AlexR I appreciate both: the edit and the respect :).

Comment: It wouldn't be "cool"--it would be correct typography. (+1 for good quibble though)

Answer (score 20):

There seems to be a lot more whitespace in various places than before.

What immediately stands out to me as not-very-pretty is that there's too much vertical space between the question title and the dotted line below it, on a question page.

Also, consider this screenshot from my profile summary page:

[image: cropped screenshot]

1. There's too much vertical space between the subheadings and the horizontal line below it.
2. The sub-tab buttons (votes/activity/newest) are too far above the horizontal line. At the very least, the bottom edge of the buttons should be flush with the baseline of the subheading.
3. The frames and other decorations around the vote counts take too much emphasis from the vote counts themselves. Do they need to be so wide? I'm not going to get more than 9999 votes on any of my answers. And even more, the *tallness* of those frames seems to be what determines the item height in the list, so if the frames were *not* there, there would be room to display more actual information.

---

Finally the line spacing in profile > "all actions" > "comments" looks excessive to me.

Comment: Second this; I recall being similarly put off when Gmail changed their look to add more whitespace around everything. Designers may think it looks cooler, but it makes it harder to get *actual work* done due to the added scrolling and eye movement. Yes, some negative space is good; but too much is just drawing attention to the design at the expense of the content.

Comment: 100% agreed @Mario.  I deeply abhor recent trends toward excessive marginal whitespace (Facebook, Reddit, etc).  I want to spend time reading, not scrolling.

Answer (score 20):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The free form flag has a text box which exceeds the size of the dialog.

(**Edit:** Four months without this being fixed, here's what needs to be changed, the "textarea" class for this input box should be set to 63 columns, and not 80.

Comparing with the CSS contents on MathOverflow, there the width is set explicitly to 575px (which is smaller than what 63 columns gives), by having

> .mod-attention-subform textarea {font-size: 12px; width: 575px; padding: 5px; }

in the CSS itself.)

Due to popular demand, here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Other relevant details, Firefox 36.0.4 on Arch Linux 64bit (kernel 3.19.2)

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot perhaps to add clarity?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this because I'm lazy when it comes to printing screens. Click flag, choose "Other" (the last option), and see for yourself.

Comment: Maybe I'll add it for you later by editing it into your post :p but I'm too lazy now myself...what a dilemma.

Comment: No-repro here. Details might be needed.

Comment: @quid: Fine. I've added a screenshot instead of sleeping.

Comment: Thanks and good night!

Comment: +1 for useful quibble and not sleeping.

Comment: Haha, love how the dialog says "Something not quite right?"

Comment: @Mario: I didn't pick up on that. Nice!

Comment: [Also reported on meta.SE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283939/flag-for-diamond-moderator-textarea-breaks-out-of-the-dialog) (but marked as a dupe of a [meta-tag:status-completed] bug there). I've had a CSS fix for this bug in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) for some time now.

Answer (score 16):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for your feedback, it's now fixed and  will be live after our next production build.

---

The gold badge icon is positioned too low in the topbar. For example, here on Meta:

[image: badges]

Comment: This is not an issue only in the topbar; the vertical placement of the badge symbols appears to be different from each other site-wide. See for example [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai6Y7.png) and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jnrMA.png).

Comment: And in Opera, the badge symbols are misplaced horribly all over the site. [Screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/INxgM.png).

Answer (score 15):

I think the orange on meta has something pretty agressive (even more in contrast to the surrounding grey/black) and therefore is not meta suited. A more "calm" color would be good, particularly for questions involving opinions.

Comment: Specifically, the comment's content gets overshadowed (is it a word?) by its author's name - a completely peripheral info.

Comment: @AlexR I have no idea if the word exists, but your point is clear (to me at least) and I definitely agree with you.

Comment: Seems it actually is a word ([definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overshadow)) and correct in this context :)

Comment: For what its worth, it is like this on all the metas of sites in beta. (One thing is that it might not go as good together with thet red in the logo and in the top menu.)

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I think its more a bug than anything else (or maybe there is a good reason for that). In profile, when I pass my mouse over my questions some grey lines appear (one or two, depends where is the mouse). However these lines do not appear for any other list in my profile.

[image][image]

May be relevant: I use Chrome

Comment: I have the same thing in Firefox

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I just fixed this one, it'll be live after our next production build.

Comment: @StéphaneMartin Ok, thank you for fixing it so quickly :).

Comment: btw I think the icons are so big and therefore seems ugly, at least to me.

Answer (score 13):

Comment turned answer per request.

The choice of the new font face is horrible. It is much thinner than before. Instead of a much sharper image as what one would naively think, it makes it much harder to read (especially for those with poor eyesight).

Comment: Can you pinpoint the change that happened? I _think_ (but am not sure) than the color of the body of posts went from `#111` to `#222`. (I didn't save the old stylesheet for comparison.) I don't see any other changes; the font family is still Georgia.

Comment: @Woodface, I cannot. I don't know what is the old/new font family used. I'm sure the font has changed because the serif of the font now looks more prominent.  That part is not the problem, the problem is the new font now too "thin". I now feel very uncomfortable simply looking at the text.

Comment: @achillehui I agree with you. Much harder to read.

Comment: I’ll have to disagree here: there are quite a few things about the change that I don’t like, but the font isn’t a problem, though my eyes are deteriorating significantly. I’m not sure whether the image is sharper, but it’s definitely not harder for me to read.

Comment: In particular, the font used in the side bars for 'Related questions' and 'Hot network' is much less readable.

Comment: @Woodface Actually we didn't change the font, we just un-bolded it, do you really think a 17px regular serif font is hard to read? I do agree sometimes designers can get crazy with super-light font, but this one seems to be pretty mainstream for me

Comment: This is now fourth monitor on which I look at it and it feels better on all of them.

Comment: @StéphaneMartin I'm not the one complaining... It seems achille hui is talking about the main font (post body), while daw is bringing up sidebar headings. I have no issues with either thing; and I don't know why anyone would call dark-blue 17px font "much less readable".

Comment: @Woodface , please take a snapshot of what's on your screen and your previous comment. If you re-read it 15 years from now,  you will know the answer.

Comment: ^ Better yet, take a good photograph of your screen.  On the two screens I use regularly it is indeed harder to read, @StéphaneMartin.

Comment: @achillehui With or without browser zoom? My zoom setting is 110% on large desktop screens and 125% on my laptop.

Comment: @Woodface I'm using firefox and I don't know the exact zoom factor. I'm using the zoom setting with 3 "+" before. Now I need to zoom it with 4 "+".

Answer (score 13):

Some of the link colours have been darkened to such an extent that they are hard to discern from the other text (particularly on some backgrounds):

[image]

As one can see, "help center" and "edit the question" are hardly identified as links. Once clicked ("improve the question"), the contrast is a bit better, but something needs to be done about this. I want links to clearly stand out (compare links on meta).

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I don't care about all the other changes, really, but *please* keep the "last seen" status $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ for users who logged on SE less than 30 minutes ago. The $\color{orange}{\text{orange}}$ color was reserved for those who logged on between 30 minutes ago to 1 hour ago. Now this is confusing for me to see $\color{orange}{\text{orange}}$ for just "9 minutes ago".

[image]

Speaking of $\color{orange}{\text{orange}}$ though, I must remark that for some reason, the person who designed this new layout may be obsessed with this color. Look at our names and timestamps on this page, for example, just as @Surb pointed out in his own answer.

Comment: Totally obsessed. I liked the grey background for block quotes; but now it's some variant of orange. Just like the rest of the palette.

Comment: Eh, to be fair now people will stop complaining that main and meta look too similar.

Comment: @Najib: They *never* looked similar!

Answer (score 11):

Let us talk about the [review page](https://math.stackexchange.com/review):

[image]

In order:

1. Misalignment between adjacent text segments
2. Excessively large spacing
3. Off-center text
4. Huge button, small text

Comment: @Asaf Thanks. Somehow the software thought for itself, and added an extra http protocol.

Comment: Well, maybe it just wanted to be sure it's there. Like stapling twice.

Comment: I think the problem with 4 is that the text is disproportionately small compared to the button. It used to be bold IIRC, so that may be why I feel that way.

Comment: I do not see the issue with 4 (except possibly for what @NajibIdrissi says). The point is not if one can see them, but if it is easy to click them. Given that some have an irreversible effect that is triggered without confirmation they'd better be too large than too small (especially as there is ample space there anyway).

Comment: @quid: The large buttons bother me because the whole website seems to be full of negative spaces.

Comment: @quid (and Najib) You are probably right. I think I would feel differently if the text was bigger. This is also in line with the reason for having big buttons.

Comment: It's like the designers took all of the contrast they had and put it into the review queue buttons.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another visual *ugggh* effect:
[image]

Just remove that borderless look, it looks annoying:
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty okay with no border. It brings attention to the unaccepted questions which presumably are the ones in need of greater attention anyway.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt To mee it creates the impression that the accepted marker has "spilled" out of its "box" - makes me somewhat uncomfortable looking at it :'D

Comment: Don't cry over spilled colorboxes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila :'(

Comment: I'm okay in general with having a borderless background color for an emphasis or box effect, but it looks half-done and visually inconsistent to me that _some_ of the items in the list have a border while others don't. When there is not one of the parallel styles that's unambiguously the "more decorated" one, the design sends mixed and confusing signals.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Precisely my problem. Feel free to edit that remark in to make it a better "answer".

Answer (score 10):

Maybe I'm the only one, but I really dislike the new upvote arrows for comments.  They seem much shorter than they used to be---I think it's because now they are just triangles and have no "stem." This makes it much harder for me to click on them.

Comment: Especially when using a handheld device with the full interface (because the mobile interface is atrocious).

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) I pushed a fix, it will be live after our next production build. The preview should look the same as the actual post now. If you still issues, please post a comment here.

---

The preview window no longer faithfully reflects what will be displayed in the answer. It seems that the preview may be using a narrower window, perhaps because of the large whitespace borders. For a simple example see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1209693/242) and note that in the preview one line breaks after "depends" in the preview, but after "depends only" in the answer.

In the past the preview was *precisely* faithful to the rendering in the answer. It is unfortunate that this is no longer true. For me, this will  complicate composing answers since I often strive for interline alignment of semantically associate items in order to aid in comprehension. That is much more difficult to achieve when there is poor correspondence between the preview and the answer.

Also noticeable in the example: the link highlighting seems to have less contrast than in the prior version (and even less in the preview: I can hardly discern the links in the preview, even on a high-quality (IPS) monitor).

Comment: I'm currently working on this issue, I will post a fix as soon as possible

Comment: @StéphaneMartin Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for your feedback, it's now fixed, I moved all assets by 1px. It will be live after our next production build.

---

Yet another misalignment issue: The vote score between the arrows is not centered. It appears to be one or two pixels off to the right.

[image]

This seems to be an issue in Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox and Opera.

Comment: My Firefox doesn't have this issue. Note that the CSS says `text-align: center` on it. Maybe that's a client-side problem, maybe a browser specific.

Comment: @AlexR You're right, Firefox doesn't have this issue for me either, and neither does Opera. However, with Internet Explorer the vote score is misplaced in the same fashion.

Comment: Interesting. Since IE can't really be considered a browser, the chrome problem remains...

Answer (score 8):

On the main page the score and answer counts have font size 17px; inside the question, the score is shown with size 20px which is quite annoying.

Both sizes should be 20px. Or larger.

Answer (score 8):

There is a line break between the word "undelete" and the number of votes that have already been cast, when the question has been edited. It wasn't present before the update and there should be enough horizontal space for everything to fit on one line.

[image]

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 41.0.2272.101 on Windows 8.1, if it makes any difference.

Comment: What's your screen resolution?

Comment: You might be onto something @Asaf, I actually don't see the linebreak on this computer (1920x1080) but I did on my SP3 (2160x1440 in theory but there's some DPI scaling mystery going on). Either that or it's been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: My bets are on the former.

Comment: Ahah! I actually see it on this computer but not on every post. I see it on [this one for example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019837/is-the-statement-the-sun-orbits-the-earth-true-false-or-ambiguous) (it's already been linked on meta somewhere so I'm not too scared of the meta-effect). Though this one has a reopen vote.

Comment: I still don't see it; but I suspect that I know why. There is a reopen vote, and things get "pushed down". I actually noticed a similar CSS bug this morning, but they already changed the CSS so it's not relevant anymore (at least for now).

Comment: Looks fine to me but it really bothers me that the vertical alignment between "share/.../flag" and "edited" isn't the same.

Comment: I see it broken as the screenshot on my Nexus 4 (using Firefox).

Comment: Regardless of how it looks on any person's display, this should pretty clearly be a non-breaking space.  I see the same problem in the formatting of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158773/how-do-people-who-study-intensely-abstract-mathematics-imagine-or-understand-t) on my 97×97 PPI Lenovo Thinkpad W540 (2970x2001 pixels) under Firefox 36.0.1.

Answer (score 8):

In comment threads, deleted accounts appear exactly the same as others. The username is even underlined on hover, suggesting it's a link. This is misleading and inconsistent with the appearance of usernames of deleted users under their posts.

[Example here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272336/distinguished-map-that-straightens-a-curve/272365#comment597470_272365) (compare with the username under the post.)

Answer (score 7):

I see problems with horizontal spacing after formulas, see image. The third marked formula reads $adj(AB)=adj(B)adj(A)$, where the comma is apparently almost invisible.

[image]

Comment: I also noticed that yesterday, but maybe you meant horizontal spacing?

Comment: I've had this problem before the new lay-out.

Comment: This may be an older one. Daw, check whether reloading the page improves the situation. That fixed the old problem, at least.

Comment: This is a MathJax issue, not a CSS design issue.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried to ignore it, but the 10px padding on the question, answer and comment boxes is unbearable. Could it please be reduced to 5px or so?

At the same time, please cut the padding of edit summary, title and other one-line input boxes by half (so 4px top/bottom, 5px left/right).

Comment: I guess it is possible to get used to this, but I have, on more than one occasion, been trying to move the cursor "too far left" since the change :-). IOW, +1.

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) It's now fixed, it'll be live after our next production build.

---

Several issues about the color of the bounty markers were raised. But I have an issue with the size of the awarded bounty labels.

The text is just too small! See the screenshot on the left.

[image: mini bounty text]                  [image]

The problem lies in the `.bounty-award` class, which adds `font-size: 0.8em`, disabling that results in a proper sized font. If you want to make it slightly smaller (perhaps the box overflows), then `0.9em` or even explicit `12px` will make it much much better (see the screenshot on the right, with the `font-size` modifier disabled).

Answer (score 6):

The size of the text in the [review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) has become very small:
[image: Small size font]

I don't really see a good reason for that, so it may just be a bug, but if it's an actual change I dislike it. It's small enough that it becomes hard to read.

Answer (score 6):

Has there always been two lines below each question when there are comments (one to separate the question from the rest, one to bound the first comment)?

[image]

I'm almost sure that the answer is no (and there is only one line on other sites). Is this a bug? It's a bit jarring in any case.

Answer (score 6):

On the main site the "cite" and "close" links in the box one gets when clicking "share" are *quite* hard to notice now (due to the color, darkblue on darkgray).

Comment: In fact, I cannot even see the "cite" and "close" links.  If quid had not posted here, I would have thought they had been removed in the update.

Comment: @GEdgar it seems unchanged to me.

Answer (score 5):

On the question pages (but not on the front page or the main question list), the profile links next to people's gravatars under their posts seem to have lost their blue color.

This means that everything posted by a user12345 now looks like they've *already* deleted their account and therefore won't be back.

For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207162/using-hodge-star-and-differential-forms-is-this-analysis-correct) I see:
[image: screenshot]

(Possibly most relevant for experienced users who're used to a black "user12345" meaning "deleted account").

Comment: Could you link to a sample? For me they appear in a somewhat darker blue (`#003b52`), but not black. This is the same color as the "add a comment" link

Comment: If they'd be deleted there'd be no gravatar. If there is no other reason, this seems like a non-issue. (Also what  AlexR said.  )// Also deleted users (now?) seem light-grey.

Comment: @quid: Well, it also looks untidy that the profile links are in nice linky blue in the question list, but uncolored on the question pages.

Comment: @HenningMakholm They aren't uncolored, but their coloring scheme is inconsistent. This might be a (valid) point of criticism.

Comment: As said they are not uncolored  (here) but seem to have the same color as other itmes (the "add comment" and the "heading"). If anything I find it surprising why not this color is also used on the frontpage. // Also on your screen-shot the colors are  different; I think you should at least update the post to remove the clearly wrong claims. (It is not black and deleted users are not even black, in addition to not having a gravatar and points attached.)

Comment: @quid: On my monitor it is so close in color to the *asked* line above it that I have to look very hard to see any difference, and even then I’m not absolutely certain that I see one. It definitely does not look like a link.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree that the colors are not easy to discern (and it should depend on the monitor and even on the angle under which one looks at it).  One might say they are barely different. [I hope this time you do not have any issue with my usage.] I also agree that the color does not highlight the fact that text is click-able.  (Personally I do not see a need to high-light this fact though, and more generally I do not see a need to draw attention to the user-name.   But this is orthogonal.) I continue to hope OP will revise the post, for example along the lines of your comment.

Answer (score 5):

1. It's impossible to click "edit tags" if the element causes a line break. Moving from [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) downwards will let it disappear again.
   [image]
2. A very related issue is with the same question, the editing box shows only two tags:
   [image]
   To see this layout bug, try to [edit the first revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1209021/edit/da49ed12-bfaf-452b-92ec-1b3c6cf802b2). If the box showed half of another tag, it would be more obvious, that these are not the only tags:
   [image]

Comment: I think both have nothing to do with the new layout (or at least it is tangential to it).  In any case I was aware of both general phenomena since a long time; it's the same on other sites (MO and MESE).

Answer (score 4):

Per Tim Post's comment about providing feedback "in the form of answers that illustrate *one* particular thing at a time that you find suboptimal":

I really do not like the blue bounty indicators. I find them to be *literally* suboptimal compared to the previous red bounty indicators.

**Elaboration:** What is generally the main reason that people give to explain a bounty? It's to $\color{red}{\mathbf{\text{draw attention}}}$ to a question. People give up their "precious reputation points" to draw attention to a question or other questions of interest to the bounty giver. To $\color{#08F}{\mathbf{\text{draw attention}}}$ with the blue color does not seem as effective. In terms of red being "aggressive" in the context of a bounty--it's *meant* to be aggressive in the sense of "STOP! Look and read." The red is much more vibrant, as it should be in the case of bounties where users are effectively "paying with reputation" for more aggressive attention-calling to questions.

Comment: I downvote as I consider it as an improvement.

Comment: @quid To each his own, but I think there is a reason people almost exclusively use the red color in answers to provide clarity (with other colors *after* having already used red)--in my opinion, red stands out much more than blue just in terms of optics.

Comment: I do not feel like discussing this a lot; I only commented as I thought the purpose of the dv might not be clear. (I disagree in several ways though.)

Comment: @crash Not sure about you, but I usually use `maroon` (because it's less aggressive and more readable than plain `red`) and `blue`, then `green`. The blue bounty icon however, doesn't bother me, since it's always in the same place I feel no need for it to be colored in an outstanding way.

Comment: @G-man: Possible duplicate of [I think I'm the target of a rude joke in chat](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/i-think).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh okay that clears it up, I'll just delete that comment.

Comment: @Henning: Assuming G-man commented about the link in crash's profile, it is much trickier because the URL is hidden.

Comment: @Jonas: Yes, that was the original comment.

Comment: @AlexR Please see my modified question; maybe it will clear things up.

Comment: @G-man You're not as special as you think ;) Shhhh. You guys are giving away the fun of it :( [For anyone interested, Henning Makholm was right, but I used the Google URL shortener to prevent users from seeing the direct source]

Comment: @crash I understand your point, but I disagree. The incentive for answering bounty questions is the awarded rep (simplified), not the red icon next to the question.

Comment: @crash I thought you were making fun or something, i didn't really think that you were a big fan

Comment: @AlexR My point is that red is far more effective in bringing attention just in terms of optics. But anyway, we seem to be at an impasse. Agree to disagree.

Comment: @G-man I'll probably change it soon to something better / more informative. Obviously I wasn't singling anyone out. Just a fun thing to perplex some people. Glad to see it worked  :D  and hopefully you don't take any offense as clearly there's none meant.

Comment: @crash Yes. Peeking at the vote count, this one seems particularly controversial ;)

Comment: @AlexR It certainly would seem you are right about this being pretty controversial...I don't think I've ever had an answer with something like +8/-7 (as it currently stands anyway).

Comment: Maybe exchanging the blue of bounties and the orange of meta could be a solution,.

Comment: @Surb While I definitely would like to go back to the way things were, I think what you suggested would be an improvement on the way things are currently.

Comment: I’m downvoting not because I disagree with your justification — I don’t — but because I don’t think that the change is a problem. I rarely see bounties and pay no attention to those that I do see, and I suspect that those who do pay attention to them will still do so.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That's a fair point I think. Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Blue always gets my attention. :)

Comment: @Blue Fair point. Probably even more so when there's a little "@" in front of it eh? ;)

Answer (score 4):

When picking a suggested duplicate with many answers, there is no separation between the answers in the duplicate selection dialog.

On the main site, where answers can be longer, this is even more confusing, since the score does not appear so close to the top, so it's even harder to say where one answer ends and another begins.

[image]

The problem is when there are many long answers, and you want to quickly scan through them and see if you can find some relevant keywords. Since the line stretches through the entire dialog, you can just scan the left and middle parts of the dialog.

Currently in order to find out when an answer ends and a new one begins you have to move your eyes constantly and look for the user symbol and whatnot. This means that the focus shifts all over the dialog, instead of being focused at one area, and that's tiresome and distracting.

So please bring back that separator line! It was helpful!

Comment: Ugh, fine, I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: I did not dv but the visual separation with the block for the user-info and the  acompanying withe space seems good enough to me. Even more so as which info is in which answer is not even that relevant at that point.

Comment: Yes, but if you roll down quickly, to review the answers and see if one of them matches the one you want to close, you might skip this and it means that you can't just scan real quickly and look for sharp visual cues around the area where the text is, you have to focus on two opposite sides of the dialog. This is just bad design. I agree it would have been fine if the site were in Hebrew, and the text was reversed. But it's not in Hebrew. So it's not as fine.

Comment: I cannot really follow. But since I would not mind having a line, and you think it will help you. So there, I endorse your proposal. (With you update I also understand the point better; this was why I added the "whitespace" as the issue that it is on the wrong side occured to me too.)

Comment: quid, I've also added (and a bit expanded) this reason to my post, to help and sell this point to other people too.