# A comment has no delete button and no link to user profile

Tags: support, comment, deleted-accounts

Long time ago I've posted a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397492/relation-between-hi-i-and-hi-j-when-i-subset-j). Surprisingly, now the delete X button is not available, but instead I can upvote it!!! Moreover, although my username is blue, there is no link to my username's page as usual. Is this a new feature or a bug?

Comment: I'm amused. I'd thought you'd changed your displayname for this to be an April Fools prank. But I now see that you changed your displayname just over a year ago. Lots of foresight? Very fascinating.

Comment: So long ago that it was before you created your account :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That comment was posted from an account that was since deleted.

Unfortunately, after the redesign the names of deleted users in comments create the impression that the user still exists (they are not greyed out). I have [reported this bug](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20130/147263).