# Tabs 'Questions' and 'Answers' on user profile aren't readable when selected

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

On my [profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228959/glorfindel?tab=profile) (and I'm sure [yours as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile)), in the Top Posts section, the active tab ('Questions' or 'Answers') isn't readable because it's white-on-white:

[image]

On [Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/228959/glorfindel?tab=profile), the selected tab *is* readable (see 'Votes' below), but once you hover over it (like I did with the 'Questions' tab), it's hard to read once again.

[image]

There's more; the [Top Activity tab](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) seems to be affected as well:

[image]

Comment: This is a way of highlighting the view options **not currently in use**. So if you click "answers", it shows a list of your answers, greys out that option and shows "questions" in a darker text. The same with the sorting options: "newest" vs. "votes". I'm sure you knew/noticed this, just adding it in case... Anyway, this is a bit annoying.

Comment: I think that depends whether you view it as a 'filter button' or a 'tab'. On other sites (where this problem does not occur, so it's linked to Math's specific design), it's often shown as a [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/77072/glorfindel) or [tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/70594/glorfindel). Also, the parameter in the URL uses the word 'tab' (but that could be a historic artifact).

Comment: I, too, have complained about too light shades of grey [before](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20083/11619):-)

Comment: *proposes to informally rename the design of Math SE to 50 Shades of Grey*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Senior Product Designer at Stack Overflow. Thanks for reporting the issue. The Fifty Shades of Math.SE will be resolved with the next production build.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, *when* is the next build? I hope not in 6-8 weeks :)

Comment: @Glorfindel It should have gone out sometime yesterday afternoon. Are you still seeing the issue? You may need to do a hard refresh in your browser to pull down the latest CSS. If you're still experiencing issues though, please let me know. :)

Comment: Yes, it's still a problem. I've cleared all caches and even tried a brand new browser I've never used before. I can see *something* has changed; the Meta site (2nd screenshot) looks now like the 1st screenshot, and the problem of the 3rd screenshot is gone (though there is no hover). Could be some server-side caching?! If you need new screenshots, please let me know.

Comment: @Glorfindel Ah, my fault. Forgot to add a class for the "Profile" tab subtabs. I've pushed a fix for this up to dev and it will go out in the next production build. I'll update my answer when it is live.

Comment: I can confirm it's much better now. Thanks!