# What is reason of making Mathstack logo red

Tags: discussion, design

I am very new here and I noticed that **everything** in $\color{red}{\text{MathStack Exchange}}$ logo are red. Is there any reason for that? Or devolopers just randomly chose red colour!!! I guess old users may have a answer.

(There may be some historical reason, maybe!!! Just curious)

---

Note: I mean by **everything** is the logo of MATHEMATICS, OP's upvote, downvote, flag, the identification of moderator sign etc.

Comment: The original design was done by a graphic designer of Stack Exchange. You can read something about it here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site 

It was then updated by another graphic designer of SE. You can read something about it here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/updates-to-the-site 

At a glance I do not see any discussion of the color specifically. But it does not seem that unusual a choice either.

Comment: @quid I like that red choice, btw! Cross-validated have better design... but MSE looks simple because of the design and I like that!

Comment: I'm looking at the front page right now, and either you have a different definition of "**everything**" than me, or a different definition of "red".

Comment: okk, @arjafi I mean by everything is the logo MATHEMATICS, OP's upvote, downvote, flag, the identification of moderator sign etc... I mean in MSE theme colour is red,  like Stack Overflow has Orange...

Comment: @MANMAID I have edited your post to include that you are talking about the logo - so that other users don't have to look for explanation in the comments. Of course, if you do not like the current wording or if there are some other things worth improving you notice, go ahead and edit your post further.

Comment: @MANMAID why did you choose an avatar which mainly red?

Comment: @Surb That is my from favourite TV manga_anime_TV series_story all time. And that is my favourite picture from that manga!!!

Comment: @MANMAID is it a straw hat? If this is the case, I agree that the anime in question is really great. Anyway, I asked you this question because I expected your answer to be as subjective as the answer to your question.

Comment: @Surb I expected a answer where developers discussed about the design(especially about colours they used) of the site!!! But as quid gave links in the first comment... I don't think such discussion happened.

Comment: It was decided after a grueling week for SE staffers, who had to make stylistic decisions (including colors and themes) for four SE sites by the following Monday.  They met up for a TGIF happy hour, and after imbibing at leisure, decided to play [twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twister_(game)), jointly, and the the winner's position of each hand and each foot on four distinct colored circles would determine the assignment of color to each of the four sites.  MSE was assigned to the color where the left hand of the lone winner touched.  Wallah!  The SE logo has been red ever since. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's simply because
$$\text{WE}$$
$$  {\Huge\color{red}{❤}}$$
$$ \text{MATH}$$

Comment: red is also the color of Satan, isn't it?

Comment: But this answer is little bit subjective, isn't!!! (just saying)

Comment: @MANMAID The most objective answer I could give is in a comment. This one is more light-hearted (no pun intended).

Comment: Yeah!!! That's right...